# Create File in /sys subdirectory

Tags: android, bash, root, tvbox

I'm working on a TV Box and I need to create a file containing "1" in a **subdirectory of */sys*.**
Is this possible in any way without rooting the device?

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

your have not permission in this folder. so can not do it.

```
shell@heroqltechn:/sys $ ls -al
drwxr-xr-x root     root              2016-12-15 18:43 bcm-dhd
drwxr-xr-x root     root              2016-12-15 16:48 block 
drwxr-xr-x root     root              2016-12-15 18:43 bus
drwxr-xr-x root     root              2016-09-08 16:04 class
drwxr-xr-x root     root              2016-12-15 18:43 dev
drwxr-xr-x root     root              2016-09-08 16:04 devices
drwxr-xr-x root     root              2016-12-15 18:43 firmware
drwxr-xr-x root     root              2016-09-08 16:04 fs
drwxr-xr-x root     root              2016-09-08 16:04 kernel
drwxr-xr-x root     root              2016-09-08 16:04 module
drwxr-xr-x root     root              2016-09-08 16:04 power
shell@heroqltechn:/sys $ mkdir abc
mkdir: 'abc': Permission denied
```

Comment: what about editing the file /system/bin/preinstall.sh and adding an 'echo 1 > /sys/.... ?